# ExpandableListView onChildClick doesn't fire (in master/detail flow)

Tags: android, android-fragments, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I know a lot have asked similar questions, but none of their solutions works for me.

I have a *master/detail flow* with a `expandable list` as the `list`. I can click the groups and expand them, but *I can't click the childre*n.

I have set them to selectable (at first I thought that was the problem), they do not have any `checkboxes` or images on them, just plain text. I've even set that text to not be `focusable` (as focusable elements seemed to be the problem for others).

This is what I have:
A custom `BaseExpandableAdapter`:

```
public class CabinetAndRacksExpandAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
//(some fields that probably aren't relevant)
@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
        return cabinets.size();
    }
(more override methods here, probably not relevant)

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listrow_cabinet, null);
    }
    Cabinet cabinet = (Cabinet) getGroup(groupPosition);
    ((CheckedTextView) convertView).setText(cabinet.toString());
    ((CheckedTextView) convertView).setChecked(isExpanded);
    return convertView;
    }

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final Rack rack = (Rack) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

    TextView text = null;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listrow_rack, null);
    }
    final View view = convertView;
    text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    text.setText(rack.toString());
    return convertView;
   }

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
    }
}
```

I also have a `fragment` (the list fragment in the master/detail flow). It should listen to the clicks, both child and group, so it implements those `listeners`:

```
public class CabinetListFragment extends Fragment implements ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener, ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener{
    //(some stuff that's probably not relevant)

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_cabinet_list, container, false);

        listView = (ExpandableListView) rootView;
        listView.setOnChildClickListener(this);
        listView.setOnGroupClickListener(this);

        Bundle extras = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras();
        if(extras != null)
        {
            String orderId = extras.getString(CabinetListActivity.ARG_ORDER_ID);
            order = service.getOrderFromId(service.intFromString(orderId));
        }
        CabinetAndRacksExpandAdapter adapter = new CabinetAndRacksExpandAdapter(getActivity(), service.getCabinetsForOrder(order));
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        return rootView;
    }

 @Override
 public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
        Log.d("CabinetListFragment", "onChildClick");
        mCallbacks.onChildSelected(groupPosition, childPosition);
        return true;
    }

 @Override
 public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, long id)
    {
        Log.d("CabinetListFragment", "onGroupClick");
        mCallbacks.onGroupSelected(groupPosition);
        return false;
    }

/**
 * A callback interface that all activities containing this fragment must
 * implement. This mechanism allows activities to be notified of item
 * selections.
 */
public interface Callbacks {
    /**
         * Callback for when an item has been selected.
         */
        public void onChildSelected(int groupPosition, int childPosition);
        public void onGroupSelected(int groupPosition);
    }

@Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);

        // Activities containing this fragment must implement its callbacks.
        if (!(activity instanceof Callbacks)) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Activity must implement fragment's callbacks.");
        }

        mCallbacks = (Callbacks) activity;
    }
}
```

This fragment belongs to an Activity that implements the Callback as it should:

```
public class CabinetListActivity extends FragmentActivity
    implements CabinetListFragment.Callbacks{

/**
 * Whether or not the activity is in two-pane mode, i.e. running on a tablet
 * device.
 */
private boolean mTwoPane;

public static final String ARG_ORDER_ID = "order_id";
private Service service;
private Order order;
private String orderId;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_cabinet_list);
    service = Service.getInstance();

    if (findViewById(R.id.cabinet_detail_container) != null) {
        mTwoPane = true;
    }

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(extras != null)
    {
        String orderId = extras.getString(ARG_ORDER_ID);
        order = service.getOrderFromId(service.intFromString(orderId));
        this.orderId = orderId;
    }
}

/**
 * Callback method from {@link CabinetListFragment.Callbacks}
 * indicating which item was selected.
 */
@Override
public void onChildSelected(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    if (mTwoPane) {
        // In two-pane mode, show the detail view in this activity by
        // adding or replacing the detail fragment using a
        // fragment transaction.
        Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
        arguments.putString(CabinetDetailFragment.ARG_CHILD_ID, childPosition+"");
        arguments.putString(CabinetDetailFragment.ARG_GROUP_ID, groupPosition+"");
        arguments.putBoolean(CabinetDetailFragment.ARG_RACKMODE, true);
        CabinetDetailFragment fragment = new CabinetDetailFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(arguments);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.cabinet_detail_container, fragment)
                .commit();

    } else {
        // In single-pane mode, simply start the detail activity
        // for the selected item ID.
        Log.d("CabinetListActivity", "show rack");
        Intent detailIntent = new Intent(this, CabinetDetailActivity.class);
        detailIntent.putExtra(CabinetDetailFragment.ARG_CHILD_ID, childPosition + "");
        detailIntent.putExtra(CabinetDetailFragment.ARG_GROUP_ID, groupPosition+"");
        detailIntent.putExtra(CabinetDetailFragment.ARG_RACKMODE, true);
        startActivity(detailIntent);
    }
}

@Override
public void onGroupSelected(int groupPosition) {
    if (mTwoPane) {
        // In two-pane mode, show the detail view in this activity by
        // adding or replacing the detail fragment using a
        // fragment transaction.
        Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
        arguments.putString(CabinetDetailFragment.ARG_GROUP_ID, groupPosition+"");
        arguments.putString(CabinetDetailFragment.ARG_ORDER_ID, orderId);
        arguments.putBoolean(CabinetDetailFragment.ARG_RACKMODE, false);
        CabinetDetailFragment fragment = new CabinetDetailFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(arguments);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.cabinet_detail_container, fragment)
                .commit();
    } else {
        // In single-pane mode, simply start the detail activity
        // for the selected item ID.
        Intent detailIntent = new Intent(this, CabinetDetailActivity.class);
        detailIntent.putExtra(CabinetDetailFragment.ARG_GROUP_ID, groupPosition+"");
        detailIntent.putExtra(CabinetDetailFragment.ARG_ORDER_ID, orderId);
        detailIntent.putExtra(CabinetDetailFragment.ARG_RACKMODE, false);
        startActivity(detailIntent);
        }

    }
//(more stuff that's probably not relevant)
}
```

I cannot see where my `childClick` event is different from the `GroupClick` event.
As stated, the `GroupClick` fires and is handled as intended, but the `childClick` is not even fired (I have tried logging from the onChildClick in the Fragment).
BTW, it does not seem to make any difference whether that method return true or false (naturally, since it is never called).

I have tried creating a listener directly on the childView, and that works. But I need to do stuff from within either the fragment or activity (preferably the activity, but it ought to be the fragment that listens for the event)  upon click, so that won't do.

Why is my `fragment` not notified of the `onChildClick` event when it is registered as a `listener`? Is the event never fired for some reason? Or is it handled elsewhere?

Comment: tell what you've tried so far?

Comment: I have mainly tried logging different places, and found that the listener is not notified.
I have also tried adding a `onChildClickListener` directly on the `childView` in the adapter, and that fires just fine. But it will be very messy if I have to do it from there.

Comment: Oh, and I have made sure that the children all are set to selectable.
And made the textView in the child not focusable.

Comment: I suspect that either the `fragment` is not properly registered as a `listener` or the event is handled somewhere else before it gets a chance to handle it. Maybe.

Comment: And I tried listening for an `onItemClick` instead, that didn't fire either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so here is what was the problem:

This was my listrow_rack:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="40dp"
android:clickable="true"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingLeft="40dp"
tools:context=".OrdreDetailActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawablePadding="5dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:textStyle="bold">
</TextView>

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="@android:color/black" />
```

The problem was this specific line:

```
    android:clickable="true"
```

I'm not sure why, but maybe it adds a listener, or maybe for some other reason. But when I removed it, it works.

Props to [Andras Baláz Lathja](https://stackoverflow.com/users/589302/andras-bal%C3%A1zs-lajtha) for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

Just a shot in the dark, but did you implement among those not relevant methods

```
int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
  // Return whatever the children's count is
}
```

and

```
public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() {
  return true;
}
```

In the Layout XML R.layout.listrow_rack, have you by any chence disabled the item, or associated a click listener to it that fires silently?

Comment: I did not have the `areAllItemsEnabled()`, but unfortunately it didn't help. But thanks :)

Comment: Your last point might or might not be the solution. Sort of :) Thanks ^^

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, what your are trying to do is something similar to this:

```
public class FaltasFragmentActivity extends Activity {

    //Lista de faltas
    private ExpandableListView mExpandalbeView;
    private ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter; 
    private int posicion;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.conduccion_faltas);

        mExpandalbeView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.expandable_faltas);

        mExpandalbeView.setOnGroupClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, long id) {
                // Codigo para cerra el ultiom grupo abierto antes de abrir el nuevo
                Toast.makeText(FaltasFragmentActivity.this, "pulsado group: " + groupPosition, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return false;
            }
        });

        // Listview on child click listener
        mExpandalbeView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                        int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(FaltasFragmentActivity.this, "pulsado child: (" + groupPosition + ", " + childPosition + ")", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return false;
            }
        });

        // Listview Group expanded listener
        mExpandalbeView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
                Toast.makeText(FaltasFragmentActivity.this, "pulsado expand", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        // Listview Group collasped listener
        mExpandalbeView.setOnGroupCollapseListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupCollapseListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGroupCollapse(int groupPosition) {
                Toast.makeText(FaltasFragmentActivity.this, "pulsado collapse", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(FaltasFragmentActivity.this, root, posicion, filtroBusqueda);
        mExpandalbeView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
    }
}
```

Where `ExpandableListAdapter(...)` is:

```
public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter{...}
```

This worked for me! 
Hope this helps!

Comment: I do not understand why it should make any difference whether I make my `fragment` or `activity`implement the `onChildClickListener` as opposed to, as you do here, make new listeners?
But I will try to see if it works , thanks.

Comment: I see that it seems to have no differences but I have fought a lot with this kind of expandable list and finally I got what I wanted. I thought that this different way to do it may help you. Try it and let us know if goes well.